# Binding a click event to tr elements in jQuery Datatable on() doesn't work

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am developing a table that will contain all our users which can also be changed by clicking the tablerow and editing the data in a form that will open once the click was performed.

If i have all the users loaded at page load, my code works fine.

Once i change my datatable to load the users at datatable initialisation it will only work on the first page.

If i uncomment the lower part of my `ready(function())` and delete `fnInitComplete` it wont even work on the first page.

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            tbl = $('#nutzer').dataTable( {
                "bJQueryUI": true,
                "sScrollX": "100%",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bServerSide": true,
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "sAjaxSource": "xhr.php",
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "fnInitComplete": function() {
                    $('#nutzer tbody tr').on("click", function () {
                        aufklappen(this);
                    } );
                }
            } );

            $( "#create-user" ).button().click(function() {
                $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
            });
//            $('#nutzer tbody tr').on("click", function () {
//                aufklappen(this);
//            } );
        });

        function aufklappen(row) {
            if ( tbl.fnIsOpen(row) ) {
                tbl.fnClose(row);
            } else {
                set = tbl.fnSettings().aoOpenRows[0];
                (set != null) ? (tbl.fnClose(set.nParent)) : null;
                $.post("benutzerBearbeiten.php", { 
                    funktion : "benutzerDaten",
                    id : $(row).children( "td:first-child" ).text()
                }, function(data){
                    tbl.fnOpen( row, data);
                    $( "#deaktivieren").button().click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        deaktivieren();
                    });
                    $( "#speichern").button().click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        speichern();
                    });
                }
            ) };
        }
```

After page load or page change through the datatables pagination i can manualy call

```
$('#nutzer tbody tr').on('click', function () {
    aufklappen(this);
} );
```

and the click function gets bound to the tr's perfectly.

Seems to me that the elements created by datatables-plugin are not getting up the dom to the on() handler that i defined but i cant figure out why.

---

### EDIT

Utilising "The System Restart"s answer i ended up deleting the `fnInitComplete` part and add

```
"asStripeClasses": [ "odd nutzer_tr", "even nutzer_tr"]
```

to the initialisation part and

```
$("body").delegate(".nutzer_tr", "click", function () {
    aufklappen(this);
});
```

to the `ready(function())`. The additional class `nutzer_tr` is to prevent the opened tablerow from closing.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you need live event:

```
$('body').on('click', '#nutzer tbody tr', function () {
    aufklappen(this);
});
```

or can use delegate()

```
$('body').delegate('#nutzer tbody tr', 'click', function () {
    aufklappen(this);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It solved my problem and stopped me from pulling my hair out.

Comment: Dont know why, can not see why, but this worked over `$('#nutzer tbody tr').click(function(){});`

Comment: Thanks, this is a general issue which most of unorganized JS educated developers have to face in, now I can resolve this issue in anywhere else where it occurs!