# jQuery find first cell of generated table width datatables

Tags: jquery

i writing simple contexMenu for datatable.i'm using `datatables` class for create list of data. i want to find first cell of table on right click on each that.
HTML:
    
        
            
                
                
                
                
                
                
            
        
        
        
    
jquery:

```
    $("#showTopics tbody").bind("contextmenu",function(event) {
        var aata = $(this).children('tr').children('td').eq(0).text();
        alert(aata);
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<table id='showTopics' style='line-height:18px;'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style='width:30%;text-align:right;'>X"</th>
            <th style='width:7%;'>a</th>
            <th style='width:12%;'>b</th>
            <th style='width:11%;'>c</th>
            <th style='width:9%;'>d</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

generated tbody with datatables:

below result after generated with datatables and putting between of tbody.

`row_selected` seting with jquery after using contex menu and clicking on `tr`.

how can i find that? for example after clicking on first row i must be have `7` and after clicking on second of tr `8`.

sorry for my english

```
<tr class="odd row_selected">
  <td class=" sorting_1">7</td>
  <td class="">0000-00-00</td>
  <td class="">0</td>
  <td class="">a</td>
  <td class="">aa</td>
</tr>
<tr class="even">
  <td class=" sorting_1">8</td>
  <td class="">0000-00-00</td>
  <td class="">0</td>
  <td class="">b</td>
  <td class="">bb</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Do you want to show a `<td>`-cell's context, when you click with right mouse button on it?

Comment: @Stano, yes, i want to get that(first cell of clicked tr).

Answer (score 0):

Update: the problem can be solved by attaching the handler with 'on' method as shown in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10618189/binding-a-click-event-to-tr-elements-in-jquery-datatable-on-doesnt-work#10618201) or in [this example](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#showTopics').dataTable();
    $('#showTopics tbody').on('contextmenu', 'tr', function() {
        var firstcell = $(this).children('td:first');
        alert(firstcell.text());
        return false;
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xR29m/6/)

Comment: tbody is generated with `datatables` and your code does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to the following. Instead of binding context menu on tbody, bind it to each tr

```
$("#showTopics tbody tr").bind("contextmenu", function (event) {
    var aata = $(this).find("td:eq(0)").text();
    alert(aata);
    return false;
});
```